# How to run arp command on an android phone

Tags: android, arp

I have connected three cameras to my phone and i want to know their ip addresses. In windows and linux its with the arp command but this command does not run on the android terminal . How can i run arp command on android or it there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

use this code work for me.

```
try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/net/arp");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        String output = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        Log.d("*************", ""+output);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return "";
```